# Counting Business days

Tags: formula, case, businesshours

I am looking to count business days from when a status is picked in a pick list on a case. I have the field awaiting customer input data adding today's date when the status is picked. This is working what I can't figure out is how to count the number of business days from the start date. I tried this code that I found but I am getting a Syntax Error. Any help would be great.

```
CASE(
MOD(DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
0, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - 1 - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
1, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
2, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
3, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
4, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
5, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - 2 - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
6, (TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - 2 - FLOOR((TODAY() - DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
null)
```

Comment: You didn't `MOD` any of the other values inside parentheses... What is the type of the `Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c` field? If it's already a `Date` field you can just remove the `DATE(...)` calls and replace with `...`.

Comment: Yes its just a Date field

Answer (score 0):

Copying your formula into my org and tweaking just the API Names, I was at least able to compile the formula just by changing `DATE(DateField__c)` to `DateField__c` everywhere you use the former.

Instead of:

```
DATE(DateField__c)
```

Just use:

```
DateField__c
```

Note that you do have one appropriate usage of the `DATE` function which you should leave untouched:

```
DATE(1900, 1, 7)
```

Comment: CASE(
MOD(DATE(Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
0, (TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c - 1 - FLOOR((TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c/7)*2,
1, (TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c - FLOOR((TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c/7)*2,
2, (TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c - FLOOR((TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c/7)*2,
3, (TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c - FLOOR((TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c/7)*2,
4, (TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c - FLOOR((TODAY() - Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c/7)*2,

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You missed the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by removing with what @adrian said. Its working. I have created a formula field with number. You can try the below

```
CASE(
    MOD((Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
    0, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - 1 - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    1, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    2, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    3, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    4, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    5, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - 2 - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    6, (TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c)) - 2 - FLOOR((TODAY() - (Awaiting_Customer_Input_Date__c))/7)*2,
    null)
```

Comment: So basically this is a duplicate answer.

Comment: Thank you bharath, that seemed to do the trick with the errors. I am testing it now. Thanks again everyone for all your help.